# How to upload a new version of a file by using WebScript?

Tags: java, rest, alfresco, versioning, alfresco-webscripts

I have a simple Spring application (front-end application) that loads files into the Alfresco repository. If the file already exists, its new version is not created.

[Repository web script](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.2/concepts/ws-types-data.html) is presented below:

```
public class CustomFileUploader extends DeclarativeWebScript {

    private static final String FIRM_DOC = 
        "{http://www.firm.com/model/content/1.0}someDoc";
    private static final String FIRM_DOC_FOLDER = 
        "workspace://SpacesStore/8caf07c3-6aa9-4a41-bd63-404cb3e3ef0f";

    private FirmFile firmFile;

    private FileFolderService fileFolderService;
    private ContentService contentService;

    protected Map<String, Object> executeImpl(WebScriptRequest req, 
            Status status) {
        retrievePostRequestParams(req);
        writeContent();

        return null;
    }

    private void retrievePostRequestParams(WebScriptRequest req) {
        FormData formData = (FormData) req.parseContent();
        FormData.FormField[] fields = formData.getFields();

        for(FormData.FormField field : fields) {
            String fieldName = field.getName();
            String fieldValue = field.getValue();

            if(fieldName.equalsIgnoreCase("firm_file") 
                    && field.getIsFile()) {
                String fileName = field.getFilename();
                Content fileContent = field.getContent();
                String fileMimetype = field.getMimetype();

                firmFile = new FirmFile(fileName, fileContent, 
                    fileMimetype, FIRM_DOC);
            }
        }
    }

    private void writeContent() {
        try {
            NodeRef parentNodeRef = new NodeRef(FIRM_DOC_FOLDER);
            NodeRef fileNodeRef = createFileNode(parentNodeRef, 
                firmFile.getFileName());

            ContentWriter contentWriter = contentService.getWriter(fileNodeRef, 
                ContentModel.PROP_CONTENT, true);
            contentWriter.setMimetype(firmFile.getFileMimetype());
            contentWriter.putContent(firmFile.getFileContent().getInputStream());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private NodeRef createFileNode(NodeRef parentNode, String fileName) {
        try {
            QName contentQName = QName.createQName(FIRM_DOC);
            FileInfo fileInfo = fileFolderService.create(parentNode, 
                fileName, contentQName);

            return fileInfo.getNodeRef();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public FileFolderService getFileFolderService() {
        return fileFolderService;
    }

    public void setFileFolderService(FileFolderService fileFolderService) {
        this.fileFolderService = fileFolderService;
    }

    public ContentService getContentService() {
        return contentService;
    }

    public void setContentService(ContentService contentService) {
        this.contentService = contentService;
    }
}
```

How to create a new version of a file with the same name by using Java-backed WebScript?

Does this solution correct?

Check if the file exists by using Lucene search: `TYPE:"firm:doc" AND @cm\:name:contract.png;` (for example) If exists, increment the property `cm:versionLabel` and create a new version of `Node` with all the properties (Actually, need to iterate through all the `ResultSet` and find `NodeRef` with max value of `cm:versionLabel` then increment it and create a new `Node`). Is there more elegant solution?

Answer (score 2):

The solution can be represented as follows:

```
public class CustomFileUploader extends DeclarativeWebScript {
    private static final String FIRM_DOC = "{http://www.firm.com/model/content/1.0}doc";
    private static final String FIRM_DOC_FOLDER = "workspace://SpacesStore/8caf07c3-6aa9-4a41-bd63-404cb3e3ef0f";

    private FileFolderService fileFolderService;
    private ContentService contentService;
    private NodeService nodeService;
    private SearchService searchService;

    protected Map<String, Object> executeImpl(WebScriptRequest req, Status status) {
        processUpload(req);
        return null;
    }

    private void writeContent(NodeRef node, FirmFile firmFile) {
        try {
            ContentWriter contentWriter = contentService.getWriter(node, ContentModel.PROP_CONTENT, true);
            contentWriter.setMimetype(firmFile.getFileMimetype());
            contentWriter.putContent(firmFile.getFileContent().getInputStream());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private NodeRef checkIfNodeExists(String fileName) {
        StoreRef storeRef = new StoreRef(StoreRef.PROTOCOL_WORKSPACE, "SpacesStore");
        ResultSet resultSet = searchService.query(storeRef, SearchService.LANGUAGE_LUCENE/*LANGUAGE_FTS_ALFRESCO*/, 
                "TYPE:\"firm:doc\" AND @cm\\:name:" + fileName.replaceAll(" ", "\\ ")+ "");

        int len = resultSet.length();
        if(len == 0) { 
            return null;
        }

        NodeRef node = resultSet.getNodeRef(0);
        return node;
    }

    private NodeRef createNewNode(FirmFile firmFile) {
        NodeRef parent = new NodeRef(FIRM_DOC_FOLDER);
        NodeRef node = createFileNode(parent, firmFile.getFileName());

        return node;
    }

    private void processUpload(WebScriptRequest req) {
        FormData formData = (FormData) req.parseContent();
        FormData.FormField[] fields = formData.getFields();

        for(FormData.FormField field : fields) {
            String fieldName = field.getName();
            if(fieldName.equalsIgnoreCase("firm_file") && field.getIsFile()) {
                String fileName = field.getFilename();
                Content fileContent = field.getContent();
                String fileMimetype = field.getMimetype();

                NodeRef node = checkIfNodeExists(fileName);

                // POJO
                FirmFile firm = new FirmFile(fileName, fileContent, fileMimetype, FIRM_DOC);
                if(node == null) {
                    node = createNewNode(firmFile);
                } 

                writeContent(node, firmFile);
            }
        }
    }

    private NodeRef createFileNode(NodeRef parentNode, String fileName) {
        try {
            QName contentQName = QName.createQName(FIRM_DOC);
            FileInfo fileInfo = fileFolderService.create(parentNode, fileName, contentQName);
            return fileInfo.getNodeRef();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public FileFolderService getFileFolderService() {
        return fileFolderService;
    }

    public void setFileFolderService(FileFolderService fileFolderService) {
        this.fileFolderService = fileFolderService;
    }

    public ContentService getContentService() {
        return contentService;
    }

    public void setContentService(ContentService contentService) {
        this.contentService = contentService;
    }

    public NodeService getNodeService() {
        return nodeService;
    }

    public void setNodeService(NodeService nodeService) {
        this.nodeService = nodeService;
    }

    public SearchService getSearchService() {
        return searchService;
    }

    public void setSearchService(SearchService searchService) {
        this.searchService = searchService;
    }
}
```

The content model must have a mandatory aspect `cm:versionable`:

```
<mandatory-aspects>
    <aspect>cm:versionable</aspect>
</mandatory-aspects>
```